# Receiving error "The entity type requires a primary key to be defined" for a list with a key defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have two classes Pick and PickList. I have successfully added a single Pick to the database, but now I want to add multiple Picks in a PickList to be added to the database in a single call. I keep receiving the error

> The entity type 'PickList' requires a primary key to be defined. If
> you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in
> 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

I tried making PickList Keyless, which did not work and resulted in the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an instance of type
> 'PickList' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types
> with a primary key may be tracked.

I cannot find an example in the Microsoft documentation of adding a List to the database.

**Pick**

```
    public class Pick
    {
        [Key]
        public string? Username { get; set; }

        public string? Game { get; set; }

        public string? Selection { get; set; }

    }
```

**PickList**

```
 public class PickList
    {
        [Key]
        public List<Pick>? Picks { get; set; }
    }
```

**DBContext**

```
public DbSet<PickList>? Selections { get; set; }
```

**Program**

```
app.MapPost(
    "/selections", async (PickList pick, DataContext db) => {
        db.Selections?.Add(pick);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.Ok();
    }
```

Comment: EF may just be ignoring that `Key` attribute because it makes no sense to use that property as a primary key. How could you possibly represent that in the database as a primary key? I'm not sure that your key for the `Pick` entity makes sense either. One `Pick` per user?

Comment: You need an extra PrimaryKey within your PickList class as such: `public ulong Id { get; set;}`

Comment: What's the purpose of `PickList` class? Is it intended to be an "entity" or just DTO? Because `DbSet<PickList>` means it is an entity with its own table, hence needs some valid primary key (like `int Id` or something). Are you just trying to add multiple `Pick` objects to the database? e.g. `db.AddRange(pick.Picks)`?

Comment: In RDBMS Primary Keys must be scalar or composite, but not enumerable. A `List<T>` cannot be used as a primary key.

Comment: @IvanStoev - yes, I am trying to add multiple Pick objects to the database.
Pick actually has a composite key on Username, Game and Selection so each user can select only one Selection per Game - I forgot to update that here after I switched from adding a single Pick to trying to add a List of Picks.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for the Primary keys is numbers. So it would be better to fix the models a bit and make a new migration. Try using the models this way.
Of course, you can also use strings for primary keys, but you have no benefit from this, except slower search in the database. If the entities are too many and the `int` or `long` are too shorts, you can use `Guid`

```
    public class Pick
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Username { get; set; }

        public string? Game { get; set; }

        public string? Selection { get; set; }

    }



    public class PickList
    {
        public PickList()
        {
             this.Picks = new HashSet<Pick>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IColection<Pick>? Picks { get; set; }
    }
```